# Copy a directory containing links and their targets in Linux

Tags: files

I have a directory:

```
/home/username1/dir_1
```

This directory contains two folders, folder_1 and folder_2. In folder_2 are links to files present in folder_1.

Now, I want to copy dir_1 into /home/username2/dir_2, and the links that are in the new folder_2 should point to the files that are in the new folder_1. So, the new directory /home/username1/dir_1 is completely independent from the old one /home/username2/dir_2.

Is that possible ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a copy of a directory on Linux with links](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11455846/how-to-create-a-copy-of-a-directory-on-linux-with-links)

Comment: No. From that thread: "I'd like to make a copy of the directory and link to the original from the new one. [...] I'm wondering if there is a way to create a copy of a directory by linking to the original". That is not what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, assuming that your question has somewhat mixed information about how the depencies actually should be (I presume here you've mixed dir_1 and dir_2 towards the end), rsync(1) will do that for you:

```
rsync -r -l /home/username1/dir_1/ /home/username1/dir_2/
```

Relevant switches being

```
-l, --links                 copy symlinks as symlinks
-r, --recursive             recurse into directories
```

Or you could just go with easiest possible choice, using `-a` which implies (among other things) `-l` and `-r`:

```
rsync -a /home/username1/dir_1/ /home/username1/dir_2/
```